# SwiftUI - @Published array doesn’t update child view

Tags: swiftui

Here's my model:

```
struct ChatRoom: Identifiable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: ChatRoom, rhs: ChatRoom) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    struct LastMessage: Codable {
        let isSeen: Bool
        var isOfCurrentUser: Bool?
        let createdAt: Date
        let senderId, text: String
    }
    
    let id: String
    let userIds: [String]
    var lastMessage: LastMessage
    let otherUser: User
    let currentUserAvatarObject: [String : Any]?
    let isTyping: Bool
    var blockerIds: [String]
    let archiverIds: [String]
    let messages: Int
    let senderMessages: Int
    let receiverMessages: Int
}
```

I have the `ChatRoomsListView` view which initializes its `ViewModel` like so:

```
struct ChatRoomsListView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button {
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "camera")
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            .padding(6)
                            .background(
                                Circle().foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.15))
                            )
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("Chats")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .offset(x: -20)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.chatRooms) { chatRoom in
                            ChatRoomView(chatRoom: chatRoom)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.vertical, 44)
            
            if viewModel.chatRooms.isEmpty {
                Text("It seems you haven’t chatted with anyone yet! That’s ok!")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct ChatRoomView: View {
    let chatRoom: ChatRoom
    
    private var text: String {
        chatRoom.isTyping ? NSLocalizedString("Typing...", comment: "") : chatRoom.lastMessage.text
    }
    
    private var hasUnseenMessage: Bool {
        !chatRoom.lastMessage.isSeen && chatRoom.lastMessage.isOfCurrentUser == false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                HStack {
                    if hasUnseenMessage {
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(chatRoom.otherUser.username)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                        Text(text)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    if chatRoom.lastMessage.isSeen && chatRoom.lastMessage.isOfCurrentUser == true {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }.padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here’s the `ViewModel`:

```
extension ChatRoomsListView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var chatRooms = [ChatRoom]()

    
    // -----------------------------
    
    @Injected private var chatRoomsService: ChatRoomsRepository
    @Injected private var currentUserService: CurrentUserRepository
    
    // -----------------------------
    
    init() {
        getChatRooms()
        subscribeToChatRoomUpdates()
    }
    
    private func getChatRooms() {
        guard let currentUser = currentUserService.user else { return }
        
        chatRoomsService.getChatRooms(currentUser: currentUser) { [weak self] chatRooms in
            self?.chatRooms = chatRooms
        }
    }
    
    private func subscribeToChatRoomUpdates() {
        guard let currentUser = currentUserService.user else { return }
        
        chatRoomsService.subscribeToChatRoomUpdates(currentUser: currentUser) { [weak self] chatRooms in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                for chatRoom in chatRooms {
                    if let index = self?.chatRooms.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == chatRoom.id }) {
                        self?.chatRooms[index] = chatRoom
                    } else {
                        self?.chatRooms.insert(chatRoom, at: 0)
                    }
                }
                
                self?.chatRooms.removeAll(where: { $0.archiverIds.contains(currentUser.id) })
                self?.chatRooms.sort(by: { $0.lastMessage.createdAt > $1.lastMessage.createdAt })
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

My problem is that once the `getChatRooms` is called and changes the `chatRooms` array for the first time, after that, every time the `subscribeToChatRoomUpdates` is called doesn't redraw the `ChatRoomView` child view. On the other hand, `ChatRoomsListView` gets updated properly.

Why is that happening?

Comment: So when you are on `ChatRoomView` and any changes come for that chat room you want to redraw `ChatRoomView`? also can you show code of `ChatRoom`

Comment: Show a minimal example code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
What you show does not compile and cannot be run to find what is wrong with it.
 Also, how about trying to move `class ViewModel: ObservableObject` outside the
 `extension ChatRoomsListView`.

Comment: @NiravD I added the `ChatRoom` model. All changes come from the `ViewModel`, in real-time from the `subscribeToChatRoomUpdates` method.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I edited the code I provided... I think it should build now, with the exception of the dependencies (the repositories). Also, why are you suggesting to move the `ViewModel` outside the `extension`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your implementation of `Equatable` - where it only compares `id` has broken the ability for the `ChatView` to detect a change to the `let chatRoom: ChatRoom`, so SwiftUI doesn't call `body` because the ids are unchanged between the old value and the new value. Try removing `Equatable`.

By the way, you need to unsubscribe to updates in the object's `deinit` or you might get a crash. And your use of `self?` is problematic, look into retain cycles in blocks.

Comment: You are a genius!!! That was it! Quick question... why is the use of `self?` problematic? Isn’t it the way to solve retain cycles? I know that's a question irrelevant to my original post, but you got me curious! :)

Comment: This might help, see "Therefore, make sure to not use weak self if there’s work to be done with the referencing instance as soon as the closure gets executed." here https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/weak-self/

Comment: That's a great answer! I would have never thought about specific `Equatable` conformance breaking the comparison mechanism...

**For those from the future:** some use cases, like appending your type to a `NavigationPath`, require the type to conform to `Hashable`. Make sure that your implementation of `static func ==` accounts for comparing the property you mutate that shall trigger a re-rendering of the view.